# Struggling to use TypeScript's infer with generic class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use infer to get the type from a generic, but I'm getting an error. I'm most likely applying it wrong... Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Foo<X> {
    public make(x: X): FooHandler<this> {
        return new FooHandler(this, x); // Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this extends Foo<infer X> ? X : never'
    }
}

class FooHandler<F extends Foo<any>> {

    public constructor(
        public f: F,
        public x: F extends Foo<infer X> ? X : never,
    ) {}
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8ANAfNA3gKGn6ADgK4BGIAlsNALZgDWApgBQAeAXNCgJQcLwASYAHYATEAwBOSAC4ALchAw58K6BIbSiEoXiEMA7nESDR4iUzkKANNBZcA3LnwBfbK+yhIMPibGSksNAMLNIMot6ISMIAnmhK2E54xGSU0MDwQhDSEkTA0vDmiarJFFQAZrxWRSolqexwQSFhIhHI5EJlkpwYAPyc0Bx6AG6SVSpcWK6uQA)

I'm aware I can add the generic parameter to FooHandler, but I'm trying to avoid this as I'm looking to infer multiple types this way.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) (like `F extends Foo<infer X> ? X : never`) which depend on unresolved generic type parameters (like `X` and even `this` inside your `make()` implementation) is *deferred*.  That means these types are essentially opaque to the compiler; it cannot verify that a value is assignable to it.  It errs on the side of type safety by complaining that the type `X` is not known to be assignable to `this extends Foo<infer X> ? X : never`.

I'm not sure that unassignability-of-unresolved-conditional-types is explicitly documented anywhere.  I *can* find GitHub issues where this is mentioned as a design limitation, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) and [microsoft/TypeScript#35257](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35257).  Suffice it to say that this is a sort of higher-order reasoning that the compiler can't really do.

---

If you are sure that what you are doing is safe but the compiler is not, you can always use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to take responsibility for type safety away from the compiler and place it on yourself:

```
return new FooHandler(this, x as FooHandler<this>['x']); // okay
// or return new FooHandler(this, x as any);
```

Here you are telling the compiler that you are sure that `x` is definitely of the same type as the `x` property of `FooHandler<this>`.  This compiles with no error, and as long as your assertion is correct, you'll have no problem at runtime either.  You have to be careful with type assertions; since the compiler cannot verify the assertion is correct, it also cannot usually notice that an assertion is incorrect, and then issues may well arise at runtime.

---

Given the particular example code in your question, I'd be more inclined to refactor to avoid conditional types entirely:

```
class FooHandler<X> {
    public constructor(
        public f: Foo<X>,
        public x: X
    ) { }
}

class Foo<X> {
    public make(x: X): FooHandler<X> {
        return new FooHandler(this, x);
    }
}
```

Instead of being given `F extends Foo<any>` and trying to calculate `X`, the code here starts with `X` and then calculates `Foo<X>`.  This might or might not be what you mean by "add the generic parameter to `FooHandler`".  Or possibly your actual use case really depends on the `Foo<any>` type being generic in a way that the example code does not capture.  In any case, it's useful to consider ways of writing the code in a way that takes advantage of the compiler's strengths instead of working around its weaknesses.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAUAUiUvADYjpIBiA9nQDwAaAfPsaVzAK4BG5AJbwkYEAGsIACgAeALiTMAlAvp0AEiGAATclkbYAFoKjtCXC6UwRsPTMCTAIAd1oNNOvZilGTAGiQZJCo3DS1dfV9TAG0AchlYgF0lAG5OSy4AekykOkwka1t7RxdQjwjvKICgkK0AT1T0iwBfJtamiiooMvCvRhokCBlsCB1utUZ61jMiDKReAWEyOmAobEweeGw8qSa5haERADNVPz2Mg6X5WkHh0e1xhkZBYCOsRXYAfkUkBScANywZzmSnwSFaXHa7VAkFgCGQACUIEcENt8oQOpRqBM2Bx9vxDqIJNJrspVO5evpceY5lYbHYHE5XGpyl4fMYoNVGnMIaR2lxOtiKZ4qTNziRLiJ4Cs1hstjtxRZJUgTqEWKxgbSJQSrgpmIrQXhwW0iM0gA)

Comment: The problem with this is that in my real-world case, Foo has multiple generic types: `Foo<X, Y extends MyObj, Z = void>`.

There are several classes like FooHandler, and thus they would all require to be defined as `FooHandler<X, Y extends MyObj, Z = void>`, and this adds a ton of extra code.

I think I'll just cast objects in the places where TS is struggling to do this.